# div container background-image

Tags: html, css

I created a div container. This container should get a background-image. The image is 1200 x 64px. If I write something in the div container, 1 picture should be fully shown. And if I write text over a height of 70px, 2 pictures should be fully shown. At the moment, I have to give the container a fixed height

Here is [my Page](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/image) + [the image](http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/background7j0b6tzhl1.png) and here the Code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.div_mit_background {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    
    width: 1200px;
    
    background-image: url('http://img3.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/background7j0b6tzhl1.png');
    height: 200px;
}

p{
    margin-left: 64px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="div_mit_background">
            <p>
                Here is some content.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this background repeat property, or something more complicated? If it something more complicated (you want the element height to be always x * 64px, You must use javascript for that... Or set line-height...

Comment: Yes thats right. Is that much code in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution if all you want to do is to show full background image in case of a new line, is to do the following:

- remove `padding-top` from p tag's CSS
- add this to the p tag's CSS: `line-height:64px;` so that the height of the line will be same as the height of the background-image and either one image will show or two (not one and a half etc.)

here is the updated CSS for p tag.

```
p{
    margin-left: 64px;
    color: white;
    line-height:64px;
}
```

and for the left or right padding or margins, you can set them as you please.

and don't forget to set the height of `.div_mit_background` as `height:auto;` instead of 200px.

hope it helps.

Comment: But I'm not sure he wants to have a line-height of 64px in his paragraph

Comment: I agree that it might not be the best solution but the only one i found so far without using JS.
  
@Sketpar: if you could confirm if this works for you or not, so that i can look for other solutions in the meantime.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer and the comments :) Its true i dont want to have a line height oft 64px. Maybe you can help me with JavaScript? Or could you give me some keywords? Then i can search on my own. But you help me too :D

Comment: @Skeptar Sure, i would love to. Can you explain what type of text will this be? is it possible you can either:
- Make the background image smaller
- or, make text larger? 
since these are the simplest solutions, if not, i will find a JS solution for you! :)

Comment: @Skeptar , i was checking your page. Have you tried it with `line-height:32px` , because your pattern seems great and doesn't look cropped at that size too :) try it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes i tested it yesterday but it wasnt really nice (in my opionion). Maybe you can help me with the js code. Or you can give me some keywords then i can try it by my own. Is that hard to realize in javacsript?

Comment: I updated [my Page](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/image). And i think the linge height is much to height.

Comment: I saw your current page, do you want to use the image you have placed now? if so, there's no point for line-height to be 64px, just remove that part and try it. Let me know if you want further help :)